# how to run console code for another site via our site

Tags: javascript, console, inject, inspect

I want to write a function, in which I give 2 parameters to that. First parameter is URL of website in which I want run my code into this Website, and second parameter is JavaScript code which I want to run there.
I want to inject my JavaScript code into special URL without opening that URL and without displaying code in console log.
Generally I want write a website program that go to a special website and run console automatically.

There is a website(I don't have control) that there are JQuery functions to POST data for insert database, I want write a program that when my page loaded data send to those functions. I can do this with console of browsers, now I want do this automatically and via load a page.

Answer (score 1):

I might need more clarity, but it sounds like cross-scripting which is strictly forbidden for security reasons – it can't be done. I could be wrong, however.

If you're looking for a general way to run code based on another website, rather than 'live control' another's web browser, you should be scraping that website's data. Sorry if this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: There is a website(I don't have control) that there are JQuery functions to POST data for insert database, I want write a program that when my page loaded data send to those functions. I can do this with console of browsers, now I want do this automatically and via load a page.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you because I don't know how. Just keep asking. Try remaking your question. It can be hard to get through on this website.